# How do determine truth value of conditional math expression?

Tags: logic

Lets suppose we have the following:

Determine the truth value of the given statement:
If |x|=6 then x=6

Now, how does one go about determining the truth value? 
It would be incorrect to use a counterexample -6 to prove this false since we are not dealing with a bi conditional 'if and only if' like this:

x>7 if and only if x>6
  let x = 6.5
  Then we can ge that the statement 'x>7 if and only if x>6' is false due to the left component being false and the right component being true. However in the first problem how do I determine the truth value without a given truth value of either component and with an inability to assume a truth value and determine truth/falsity via counterexample? Intuitively I know the statement is true but how do I prove this using logic?

My first attempt was to assume the first component is true and then the second component followed and was true and thus the statement was true, but this was only based upon the initial assumption that the first component was true in the first place! How do I arrive at truth value here without assumption?

Comment: "*It would be incorrect to use a counterexample $-6$ to prove this false since we are not dealing with a biconditional*"  That is not correct.  You absolutely *can* and *should* use a counterexample in this case.  "*Intuitively I know the statement is true*" No, it is false again due to the counterexample of when $x=-6$.

Comment: It is true that $x=6$ implies $|x|=6$.  The reverse implication is false.  In a similar manner, $x>7$ implies $x>6$ is true (*remembering that order is transitive and $x>7$ along with $7>6$ implies $x>6$*).  In the same way that we prove the reverse implication is false (*that $x>6$ does not imply $x>7$ by using the counterexample of $x=6.5$*) we can do the same thing for your original problem.

Comment: A key thing here is the (implicit) universal quantification. You have the statement $\forall x.|x| = 6 \implies x = 6$. To prove this false, we are free to instantiate the universal quantifier to whatever we want, and then show a contradiction. In particular, we can instantiate to $x=-6$ and then show $|{-}6|=6\implies -6=6$ is false as per Y. Forman's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth table for conditional $P \implies Q$ (you can find this online) tells us that the conditional $P \implies Q$ is false if $P$ is true and $Q$ false; otherwise it's true.

So your counterexample has to be a case where $P$ holds, but $Q$ does not.

In your example, $x=-6$ works as a counterexample. $|x|=6$ is true, but $x=6$ is false; thus $|x|=6 \implies x=6$ is false, i.e., we cannot say that whenever $|x|=6$, $x=6$.

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot. I missed that somehow. Say there existed a being that could not find a counterexample like -6, and they were not given the truth value of either component? Would the truth value of the statement therefore be unattainable until that knowledge had been acquired? Do I approach all truth-value determinations of mathematical statements by trying to find a counterexample since I am not given truth value of components in questions like above? Is there another way to solve the question above other than via counterxample?

Comment: @Sphygmomanometer: Showing that a statement like this (which generalizes over all $x$) is _false_ generally needs a counterexample. To show that it is _true_ you need a _proof_, based on an appropriate set of axioms you have chosen to believe.

Comment: @Sphyg There are a number of open problems in mathematics to which we do not know the answer that if we were capable of finding a counterexample would provide an immediate answer.  For example, all known [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) are even.  We do not yet know of a way to prove that all perfect numbers actually *are* even, nor have we yet found any examples of odd perfect numbers.  "*would the truth of the statement therefore be unattainable*" sometimes, unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You want to prove that $\neg \forall x\in R:[\space |x| = 6 \implies x=6]$ or equivalently, $\exists x\in R: [\space |x|=6 \land x\neq 6]$.